# saving form - many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to save form based data in many to many relationship. My models is as follow:

```
class Student(models.Model):
 stuName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuCity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 stuPhone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
 stuNationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 stuCreatedt = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
 def __str__(self):
     return '%s %s %s' % (self.stuName,self.stuCity,self.stuNationality)

class Dept(models.Model):
 deptId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 deptName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s' % (self.deptId, self.deptName)


   class Course(models.Model):
 courseId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 courseName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 enrolledStu = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
 students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
 dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.courseName,self.enrolledStu,self.students,self.dept)
```

which i am trying to save. my view is

```
def addStudent(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CourseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        print(form.cleaned_data)
        course = form.save(commit=False)
        course.courseName = request.courseName
        course.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect('lstDetail')
```

i tried without form.save_m2m() method but still its giving error.

```
AttributeError at /stuApp/new/
```

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'courseName'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/stuApp/new/
Django Version: 1.11.10
Exception Type: AttributeError

```
Exception Value:    
WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'courseName
```

Exception Location: C:\Users\PycharmProjects\learning\stuApp\views.py in addStudent, line 22
Python Executable:  C:\Users\PycharmProjects\learning\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4

this is from html page. on console there isn't any error its just prints the query.

basically i am unable to save data with many to many fields and relationship.

my html is

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

urls py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.listStudent,name='liststudent'),
url(r'^stuApp/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.lstDetail, name='lstDetail'),
url(r'^stuApp/new/$', views.addStudent, name='addStudent'),
url(r'^stuApp/new/$', views.addStudent, name='addStudent'),
```

]

thank you for your help and time

Comment: I suspect `request.courseName` should be `request.POST['courseName']`

Comment: thank you it solved the problem